# Is it better to have one observer of whole object or several of its children

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Assume simple character model like

```
character: {
  gold: 1000,
  health: 100,
  mana: 50
}
```

Client will subscribe to firebase to listen for changes in `gold`, `health` and `mana`. What is recommended way in terms of data usage / firebase pricing / performance to do this?

Should I subscribe to changes in `character` or have 3 subscribers to each value?

Comment: I recommend measuring the bandwidth used with https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all of your data (gold, health, mana) are changing constantly in an equally way then you can subscribe to changes in character node. If only one of those three is changing constantly then you can add a listener only on each particular child. In this case, you don't need to download the entire object if only one value is changing constantly.

Even if you use one or three listeners, don't forget to remove the listener according to the activity life-cycle like this:

```
databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

And of course, as Frank recomended, do some [tests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile) for measuring the bandwidth.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Adding a lot of listeners isn't considered bad because Firebase can handle a lot of listeners easily.